# How to update Xcode constraints during run time

Tags: xcode, autolayout

Is there any way to update your constraints while your program is running in X code? In my project I have an image moving based off of user input (tapping a button) but after a while the original constraint will come back and the image is back in its original position.

Comment: "Is there any way to update your constraints while your program is running". Yes, there is, and you have correctly discovered a situation where it is necessary to do so.

Comment: See the discussion in my book of the bad things that can happen if you use animation on the frame of a view that is positioned with autolayout, and how to solve the issue: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout